# Error in defining relation parent /child with c#

Tags: c#

I have the following table

```
PNLId   PNLCode PNLParentId Operator    Sign
0       0   ~   S
49  C   51  +   NULL
50  Z   51  +   NULL
51  Y   107 /   NULL
52  B   107 /   NULL
53  B   108 +   NULL
```

I define the following class

```
class Node
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public string Sign { get; set; }
        public Node Parent { get; set; }
        public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }

        public Node()
        {
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            //return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " " + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => x.Id));
            return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " "
            + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => string.Format("({0}, {1})", x.Sign, x.Id)));
        }
}

var map = new Dictionary<int, Node>();
var rootNodes = new List<Node>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLId"]);
    int? parentId = null;
    if (!row.IsNull("PNLParentId"))
    {
        parentId = Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLParentId"]);
    }
    string op = Convert.ToString(row["Operator"]);
    string sign = Convert.ToString(row["Sign"]);
    map[id] = new Node
    {
        Id = id,
        ParentId = parentId,
        Operator = op,
        Sign=sign

    };
}

foreach (var pair in map)
{
    if (pair.Value.ParentId.HasValue)
    {
        var parent = map[pair.Value.ParentId.Value];
        pair.Value.Parent = parent;
        parent.Children.Add(pair.Value);
        parent.Operator = pair.Value.Operator;
    }
    else
    {
        rootNodes.Add(pair.Value);

    }
}
```

For the PNLParentId 107

```
[107 Node: + 107 (, 51),(, 52)]
```

How can I modify the code above to get the right operator for 107 which is `/`?

Comment: When I run your code it shows `Node: / 107 (null, 51),(null, 52)`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `+` operator is coming from another child:

```
49  C   51  +   NULL
50  Z   51  +   NULL
```

Depending on the order the rows are fetched, the `49` or `50` `Node` sets the `Operator` for the parent `Node` `51` to `+`.

**EDIT**

It hinges on this line of your code:

```
parent.Operator = pair.Value.Operator;
```

From your post, you assume that the `parent` is `107` and the `pair.Value` is `51` or `52`. This, when assigning the child to the parent, the `/` operator is assigned to the `107` `parent`.

However, when the `49` and `50` children are processed, the `+` operator is applied to their parent, `Node` `51`. Thus, when applying the operator from `Node` `51` to `parent` `107`, the `+` operator from `49` or `50` is applied to `107` via `Node` `51`.

Comment: the order can interfere ? please explain me more .

Comment: So how can I modify the code ? I am working on it over than two days .I didn't figure out .

Comment: You'll need to define the requirements better before I can suggest something that will absolutely work. What should the `51` node operator be? Can it be different than the `107` parent? I have merely answered why it doesn't work.

Comment: the operator for node 51 could be different the 107 parent

Comment: Should I start from root nodes when I update field operator ?

Comment: Build your node tree first. Then start at the root nodes copying the operator from the children. Progress to the children and copy their children's operator.