# Get parent/child relation from table

Tags: c#

Say that we have the following table

```
PNLId   PNLCode PNLParentId Operator    Sign
0       0   ~   S
49  C   51  +   NULL
50  Z   51  +   NULL
51  Y   107 /   NULL
52  B   107 /   NULL
53  B   108 +   NULL
```

I define the following class Node to get the relation  parent/child

```
class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Sign { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " " + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => x.Id));
        return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " " + 
               string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => string.Format("({0}, {1})", x.Sign, x.Id)));
    }
}

var map = new Dictionary<int, Node>();
var rootNodes = new List<Node>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLId"]);
    int? parentId = null;
    if (!row.IsNull("PNLParentId"))
    {
        parentId = Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLParentId"]);
    }
    string op = Convert.ToString(row["Operator"]);
    string sign = Convert.ToString(row["Sign"]);
    map[id] = new Node
    {
        Id = id,
        ParentId = parentId,
        Operator = op,
        Sign=sign

    };
}
```

Any idea how to complete the code above to get the relation parent/child correctly ?Any help would be the most appreciated !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in defining relation parent /child with c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515175/error-in-defining-relation-parent-child-with-c-sharp)